# Как обработать массив быстро параллельными вычислениями?

Tags: c#, оптимизация

Решил накидать простенькую задачу: выполнить какие-нибудь операции над большим блоком данных. И это все распараллелить. Это можно сделать 2мя способами:
1. Параллелить вызов коротеньких процедур. Но тогда будет очень много времени тратиться на то, чтобы передать управление другому ядру. Ведь так? ну нет смысла параллелить операцию 2+2.
2. Параллелить обработку блоков данных. Логично предположить. что когда параллельно запускаться будут тяжелые процедуруы, эффект от параллельности будет гораздо выше.
Однако оказались весьма странные результаты. Почему-то первоначальный эффект от параллельности отрицательный.
Вот код простой программки, которая наглядно всё демонстрирует:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;
namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        double [] _dArray = new double[10000000];
        double[] _dArray2 = new double[10000000];
        int _iThreads = 8;
        int _iSizeBlock;

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _iSizeBlock = _dArray.Length / _iThreads;//размер блока

            //заполним массив случайно
            Random r = new Random();
            for (int i = 0; i < _dArray.Length; i++)
            {
                _dArray[i] = r.NextDouble();
                _dArray2[i] = _dArray[i];
            }
             richTextBox1.Text = "1 итерация:\r\n";
             for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
             {
                 ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions
            {
                MaxDegreeOfParallelism = i
            };
                 Stopwatch st1 = new Stopwatch();
                 st1.Start();
                 Parallel.For(0, _dArray.Length, options, parallelOne);
                 st1.Stop();
                 richTextBox1.Text += i.ToString() + " поток, время: " + st1.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString() + "\r\n";
             }

             richTextBox1.Text += "Блок итераций:\r\n";
             for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
             {
                 ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions
                 {
                     MaxDegreeOfParallelism = i
                 };
                 Stopwatch st1 = new Stopwatch();
                 st1.Start();
                 Parallel.For(0, i, options, ParallelBlock);
                 st1.Stop();
                 richTextBox1.Text += i.ToString() + " поток, время: " + st1.Elapsed.TotalSeconds.ToString() + "\r\n";
             }

        }

        private void ParallelBlock(int iIndex)
        {
            int iStart = iIndex * _iSizeBlock;
            int iEnd = iStart + _iSizeBlock;
            //iIndex - номер блока
            for (int i = iStart; i < iEnd; i++)
            {
                _dArray[i] = Someoperations(_dArray[i]);
            }
        }
        private void parallelOne(int iIndex)
        {
            _dArray[iIndex] = Someoperations(_dArray[iIndex]);
        }
        private double Someoperations(double dInput)
        {
            double Result = Math.Sin(dInput) * Math.Log(dInput + 10);
            Result = Math.Pow(Result, 10);
            Result += Math.Abs(Math.Cos(Result));
            Result += Math.Sqrt(Result);
            Result = Math.Pow(Result, 2);
            return Result;
        }
    }
}
```

А вот результат.

> 1 итерация:
>
> 1 поток, время: 2,5947303
>
> 2 поток, время: 1,5046816
>
> 3 поток, время: 1,2435103
>
> 4 поток, время: 1,1743574
>
> 5 поток, время: 1,8177255
>
> 6 поток, время: 1,8564871
>
> 7 поток, время: 1,7038264
>
> 8 поток, время: 1,7404472

Блок итераций:

> 1 поток, время: 1,2824387
>
> 2 поток, время: 1,2592897
>
> 3 поток, время: 1,3303499
>
> 4 поток, время: 1,3710368
>
> 5 поток, время: 1,4195757
>
> 6 поток, время: 1,4460356
>
> 7 поток, время: 1,5213963
>
> 8 поток, время: 1,6072681

Как видно, во втором случае результат очень плохой. То есть распараллеливание медленно отрабатывает. Почему так? Ведь по логике второй способ распараллеливания должен быть лучше первого?
Я нашел вот такое в Интернете.

```
Thread.BeginThreadAffinity();
foreach(ProcessThread pt in Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads)
{
    int utid = GetCurrentThreadId();
    if (utid == pt.Id)
    {
        pt.ProcessorAffinity = (IntPtr)(_iCPUThread); // Set affinity for this
        AllIterations();
    }
}
Thread.EndThreadAffinity();
```

Может быть таким способом можно как-то более оптимально решить мою проблему и код получится ускорить? Можете подсказать? А то совсем как-то тупик. Можно ли код, который я написал выше, распараллелить с использованием приведенного выше мной примера? Основная сложность заключается в передаче индекса в поток. Ведь массив по индексу ведь обрабатываю
Спасибо

Comment: Сколько у вас ядер процессора? Что с Hyper Threading?

Comment: У меня у процессора 12 логических ядер. 6 из которых физические. i7-3930k

Comment: `Thread.BeginThreadAffinity` делает не то. Он прибивает логический thread к системному. Это на самом деле на текущий момент не нужно, т. к. почти на всех реализациях CLR управляемый thread реализуется при помощи системного.

Answer (score 4):

Вы правы в том, что если операции лёгкие, быстрые, то их желательно выполнять в блоках. Но дело в том, что вычисления в методе `Someoperations` на самом деле тяжёлые. Если заменить тело метода на `return 0;`, то выгода от вычислений блоками становится очевидна.

А главное, у вас логическая ошибка в коде в строке:

```
Parallel.For(0, i, options, ParallelBlock);
```

Неудивительно, что время обработки последовательно увеличивается, ведь на первой итерации обрабатывается лишь часть массива (одна восьмая, в вашем случае), на второй итерации - две части и т. д. Параметр `i` нужно заменить на `_iThreads`.

Answer (score 1):

Как было указано в ответе @Alexander Petrov, у вас в коде логическая ошибка, поэтому результаты не вполне правильные. В исправленном коде время обработки уменьшается с увеличением количества задействованных потоков.

На моей машине получаются такие результаты:

```
1 итерация:
1 поток, время: 1,7375645
2 поток, время: 0,9127861
3 поток, время: 0,6447709
4 поток, время: 0,5280516
5 поток, время: 0,5156717
6 поток, время: 0,5069659
7 поток, время: 0,4636803
8 поток, время: 0,4298237
неограниченое число потоков, время: 0,4348061
Блок итераций:
1 поток, время: 2,6115381
2 поток, время: 1,3137321
3 поток, время: 0,9390005
4 поток, время: 0,6965802
5 поток, время: 0,6166681
6 поток, время: 0,5237621
7 поток, время: 0,4599443
8 поток, время: 0,4131483
```

Microsoft [советует](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd560853(v=vs.110).aspx) для вашего случая (много данных, простой короткий цикл обработки) использовать `Partitioner.Create`, в котором ваш цикл делится на части, и куски отдаются на обработку вашему коду.

Для вашего случая это выглядит так:

```
var rangePartitioner = Partitioner.Create(0, _dArray.Length);
Parallel.ForEach(rangePartitioner, (range, loopState) =>
            ParallelBlock2(range.Item1, range.Item2));

void ParallelBlock2(int iStart, int iEnd)
{
    //Console.WriteLine($"[{iStart}, {iStart}+{iEnd-iStart})");
    for (int i = iStart; i < iEnd; i++)
    {
        _dArray[i] = Someoperations(_dArray[i]);
    }
}
```

Этот код бежит за 0,470345 секунд, что вовсе не плохо. Этот код можно ещё ускорить, подсказав предпочтительную длину разбиения:

```
var rangePartitioner = Partitioner.Create(0, _dArray.Length,
                          _dArray.Length / Environment.ProcessorCount);
```

В этом случае Partitioner, судя по всему, не тратит время на возможную балансировку кусков, и выдаёт оптимальный результат, у меня в тесте это было 0,4100153 секунд.

Также неплохо справляется PLINQ:

```
ParallelEnumerable.Range(0, _dArray.Length).ForAll(ParallelOne);
```

пробегает у меня за 0,4405042 секунды.

Полный код теста:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args) => new Program().Run();

    double[] _dArray = new double[10000000];
    int _iSizeBlock;

    void Run()
    {
        // прогрев
        ParallelBlock(0);
        ParallelBlock2(0, 1);
        ParallelOne(0);

        //заполним массив случайно
        Random r = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < _dArray.Length; i++)
        {
            _dArray[i] = r.NextDouble();
        }

        Stopwatch sw;

        Console.WriteLine("1 итерация:");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
        {
            ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = i };
            sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            Parallel.For(0, _dArray.Length, options, ParallelOne);
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"{i} поток, время: {sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds}");
        }
        sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        Parallel.For(0, _dArray.Length, ParallelOne);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"неограниченое число потоков, время: {sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds}");

        Console.WriteLine("Блок итераций:");
        for (int i = 1; i <= 8; i++)
        {
            ParallelOptions options = new ParallelOptions { MaxDegreeOfParallelism = i };
            lock(this) _iSizeBlock = _dArray.Length / i;
            sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            Parallel.For(0, i, options, ParallelBlock);
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"{i} поток, время: {sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds}");
        }

        Console.WriteLine("PLINQ:");
        sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        ParallelEnumerable.Range(0, _dArray.Length).ForAll(ParallelOne);
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"PLINQ, время: {sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds}");

        sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var rangePartitioner = Partitioner.Create(0, _dArray.Length);
        Parallel.ForEach(rangePartitioner, (range, loopState) => ParallelBlock2(range.Item1, range.Item2));
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Simple partitioning, время: {sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds}");

        sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
        var rangePartitioner2 = Partitioner.Create(0, _dArray.Length, _dArray.Length / Environment.ProcessorCount);
        Parallel.ForEach(rangePartitioner2, (range, loopState) => ParallelBlock2(range.Item1, range.Item2));
        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine($"Core count guided partitioning, время: {sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds}");

        Console.ReadKey(intercept: true);
    }

    void ParallelBlock(int iIndex)
    {
        int iSizeBlock;
        lock (this) iSizeBlock = _iSizeBlock;
        int iStart = iIndex * iSizeBlock;
        int iEnd = iStart + iSizeBlock;
        //iIndex - номер блока
        for (int i = iStart; i < iEnd; i++)
        {
            _dArray[i] = Someoperations(_dArray[i]);
        }
    }

    void ParallelBlock2(int iStart, int iEnd)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine($"[{iStart}, {iStart}+{iEnd-iStart})");
        for (int i = iStart; i < iEnd; i++)
        {
            _dArray[i] = Someoperations(_dArray[i]);
        }
    }

    void ParallelOne(int iIndex)
    {
        _dArray[iIndex] = Someoperations(_dArray[iIndex]);
    }

    double Someoperations(double dInput)
    {
        double Result = Math.Sin(dInput) * Math.Log(dInput + 10);
        Result = Math.Pow(Result, 10);
        Result += Math.Abs(Math.Cos(Result));
        Result += Math.Sqrt(Result);
        Result = Math.Pow(Result, 2);
        return Result;
    }
}
```

Его результат (x64, Release, вне Visual Studio):

```
1 итерация:
1 поток, время: 1,7375645
2 поток, время: 0,9127861
3 поток, время: 0,6447709
4 поток, время: 0,5280516
5 поток, время: 0,5156717
6 поток, время: 0,5069659
7 поток, время: 0,4636803
8 поток, время: 0,4298237
неограниченое число потоков, время: 0,4348061
Блок итераций:
1 поток, время: 2,6115381
2 поток, время: 1,3137321
3 поток, время: 0,9390005
4 поток, время: 0,6965802
5 поток, время: 0,6166681
6 поток, время: 0,5237621
7 поток, время: 0,4599443
8 поток, время: 0,4131483
PLINQ:
PLINQ, время: 0,4405042
Simple partitioning, время: 0,470345
Core count guided partitioning, время: 0,4100153
```